# Is there a way to edit phone numbers on the Android contact list?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, contacts

I'm using Eclipse for Android and the line I'm using only for permission is the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

What I want is basically to edit all phone numbers from the contact list in a single step:

before: 08xxxxxxx after: 0(9)8xxxxxxx

I want to put "9" after "0" in all phone numbers that a user may have. Is that possible?

"edited": sorry, what i didn't say is that there is a country that needs mandatory an additional character, and its number "9" after the "0". Users hate to edit their contacts one by one, so the deal is to edit all phone numbers in one step.

Comment: Why on earth would you do that? I'd hate to have all my phone numbers 'improved' like this. Most of them would no longer work.

Comment: there is a straight forward example on android developper site to get the list of contacts. Check the intent documentation page.